# How to call module function in template file?

Tags: 7

I have one custom function in .module file. Need to call that function .template file. Below is my code snnipet:

```
function non_login_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  if(module_exists('test') && function_exists('test_get_rnd_data')){
    $vars['rnd_data'] = test_get_rnd_data();
    print_r("callled"); exit;
  }
}
```

the function exists does not return true. Is anything thing missing?

Comment: `function_exists` is a basic PHP method - if the file containing the function is included, which in the Drupal world equates to the module being enabled, there's no logical reason your code wouldn't work.

Comment: ohh got the issue. The issue was with the custom module. I had the backup of my custom module inside  module folder with the different name. Due to which it was giving the false result. After deleting and clearing cache it works out.

Answer (score 1):

Please try bellow code and use module_load_include() function.

```
function non_login_preprocess_page(&$vars) {

  module_load_include('module', 'module', 'test');   // **add this line**

  if(module_exists('test') && function_exists('test_get_rnd_data')){
    $vars['rnd_data'] = test_get_rnd_data();
    print_r("callled"); exit;
  }
}
```